# Eclipse HTML Web Page Editor source

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, html-editor

Where can I find the source code for Eclipse HTML Web Page Editor plugin - org.eclipse.jst.pagedesigner? 
I need to modify it to add my custom components (with drag-n-drop feature) and also some more properties to the existing controls.

Comment: All Eclipse source is on github at http://github.com/eclipse Modifying the editor is going to be hard work!

Comment: I suggestive taking the original repos from here https://git.eclipse.org/c/ .Sometimes the github repos are not uptodate.

Comment: I can't seem to find the .git for org.eclipse.jst. It is part of the Eclipse Web Tools Platform. Plugin name = JSF Tools - Web Page Editor. Is there a different location for the source of this project?